# doubts in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality proof

Tags: proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

[image]

This is the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality given in "One variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra" by Tom M. Apostol.

In last paragraph It is said that the right hand side has smallest value when x=... etc!

so we  proved.

My question is why we choose smallest value? why not largest value? are we allowed to choose like this? Is this logically correct to choose like this? we choose some particular x,  doesn't it went wrong if we choose like this? please explain this.

Comment: [The same method is given in khan academy too ,with some additional steps to make proof long but didn't contribute anything! Sorry if you are lover of khan academy]

Comment: Posting [scanned pages from textbooks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155600/allowed-to-post-scanned-page-from-text-book-on-se) is forbidden on SE.

Comment: i don't know that. do i need to delete this post?

Comment: Quoting from a SE site mod: "Images are ... not a shortcut to not having to type anything."  So please use MathJax to type it out.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020))

Comment: okay! next time i will type everything.Thanks for let me know it!

Comment: @GNUSupporter But it seems to be overinterpretation in this case. OP formulates question in 9 sentences, adding a part of the page, what is rather allowed private usage.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Why do you say that using scanned pages is allowed?  How do I overinterpret the linked Meta post?  The question is "Am I permitted to upload a page from a textbook on SE?", and the site mod's answer begins with a clear "no".  Can you [answer the question with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189)? OP doesn't even name the author who wrote this proof.

Comment: As far as I can measure, this is not more than half a page, and this is not a page. :-) I agree that we should fight with lazyness, but this case seems not to be a question of a lazy beginner. (Please see his activity).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I encourage using images for illustrations. However, the reason for disallowing "text images" is that [they cannot be searched](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) (from [Approach0](//https://approach0.xyz)) and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. It's ok to include the picture as long as we can answer the question *without* the picture.  In this case, OP is using it as a critical portion of his/her question.  Deleting it renders the question meaningless.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke In my 2nd comment, I suggest OP [a way to handle text images](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/141752/259305). Your last sentence contains a typical [appeal to the person](//commonsenseatheism.com/?p=3111): 1. "OP should not post a question which is undoable without the text image." 2. "However, OP is not a lazy beginner." 3. "Therefore, it's ok for OP to post a question which is undoable without the text image."  Whether "OP is lazy" or not is irrelevant to "can the question be answered without the text image".  Therefore, your argument is fallacious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$A\left(x+\frac{B}{A}\right)^2+\frac{AC-B^2}{A}$$. $A$ is a sum of squares, it can never be negative, and we want $$Ax^2+2Bx+C\geq 0$$. The first summand is $$A\left(x+\frac {B}{A}\right)\geq 0$$ for all real $x$, then our whole sum is not negative if also the second summand is non negative if $$AC-B^2\geq 0$$

Comment: if first summand is non negative .Did we still need $AC-B^2>=0$?

Comment: Yes that is what we Need, this is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, but if the first summand is strictly positive it Can be that the whole sum is not negative, and we do not Need $$AC-B^2\geq 0$$ so we use $$x=-\frac{B}{A}$$ and our first summand is Zero and it MUST be $$AC-B^2\geq 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: please forgive me for asking one more questions! doesn't it looks like a particular case ?if $x\neq \cfrac{-B}{A}$ does this inequality still make sense ?

Comment: If $$x\neq -\frac{B}{A}$$ it Can be that $$A\left(x+\frac{B}{A}\right)^2+\frac{AC-B^2}{A}\geq 0$$ without the condition $$AC-B^2\geq 0$$

Comment: Think about a quadratic equation!